# mypy does not use narrowed types inside function definitions

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have a problem with mypy. mypy does not use narrowed types inside function definitions.
I have the following code:

```py
from typing import Callable


def foo(a: str | int) -> list[str]:
    x: list[str] = ["abc", "def"]
    if isinstance(a, int):
        x.insert(a, "ghi")
    elif isinstance(a, str):
        x.insert(0, a)
    return x


def bar(a: str | int) -> Callable[[list[str]], list[str]]:
    if isinstance(a, int):
        def modify(x: list[str]) -> list[str]:
            x.insert(a, "ghi")
            return x
    elif isinstance(a, str):
        def modify(x: list[str]) -> list[str]:
            x.insert(0, a)
            return x
    return modify
```

`foo` is correctly identified as well-typed.
I believe that `bar` should also be well-typed, but mypy gives this error:

```
16: error: Argument 1 to "insert" of "list" has incompatible type "Union[str, int]"; expected "SupportsIndex"
20: error: Argument 2 to "insert" of "list" has incompatible type "Union[str, int]"; expected "str"
```

Is this a bug in mypy? Is there a way for me to type this program otherwise?

Comparing with alternative type checkers suggests this is mypy-specific. Pyright does not complain about anything here, but does if `x.insert(0, a)` is replaced with `x.insert(a, "ghi")`.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is because nested function definitions make name resolution and type narrowing pretty complex. You can fix it by just re-assigning `a` to a well-typed variable and then close over that with `modify` in each branch:

```
from typing import Callable

def bar(a: str | int) -> Callable[[list[str]], list[str]]:
    if isinstance(a, int):
        # create a new variable with the correct type while mypy
        # can keep track of what's going on
        idx: int = a
        def modify(x: list[str]) -> list[str]:
            # close over the new variable instead of `a`
            x.insert(idx, "ghi")
            return x
    elif isinstance(a, str):
        # do the same thing here
        # the explicit type annotation isn't even actually necessary
        # I just put it for clarity
        s: str = a
        def modify(x: list[str]) -> list[str]:
            x.insert(0, s)
            return x
    return modify
```

Comment: I have learned that in fact this behaviour is intentional and is because Python functions bind their variables on call, meaning that a later modification of the broadly typed variable could cause the type to change. https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#narrowing-and-inner-functions
This was brought to my attention on the Python Discord server by @hauntsaninja#5495 https://discord.com/channels/267624335836053506/891788761371906108/1043657827819995156